# Adding two times from database

Tags: php, mysql, time, addition

im a newbie in PHP and im trying to solve this situation as much as i can but still don't get/know the right answer.

I have a table with 2 columns in database with time datatype

```
Lunch     Break
00:01:00  00:00:30
```

Im trying to fetch the data and add the two times, but i always get the wrong value.
I have this code:

```
 $time[$x] =$row['break'] + $row['lunch'];
 $totalAux[$x] = $time[$x];
```

Output is : "00:00:00"

The i try this one:

```
 $time[$x] =strtotime($row['break']) + strtotime($row['lunch']);
 $totalAux[$x] = $time[$x];
```

And get an ouput of "00:00:00"

Then lastly tried this one:

```
 $time[$x] =strtotime($row['break']) + strtotime($row['lunch']);
 $totalAux[$x] = date('H:i:s', $time[$x]);
```

Output was: "09:33:14"
Please Help Guys .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ADDTIME function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) from MySQL:

```
SELECT Lunch, Break, ADDTIME(Lunch, Break) FROM table_name;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3f9c/1)

Comment: But how if i want to add 10 columns, i have a parameter count error when i use the ADDTIME()

Comment: Got it, i just have to use the ADDTIME() inside another ADDTIME() :) Thanks Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [TIMEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and [ADDTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) functions which is to get the difference or to add times respectively in `mysql` so that it would be resolved there and `php` will just have to pick it up.

You need to use also TIME_FORMAT() in order to get the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(lunch, breaks),'%H:%i:%s') as TimeTotal 
FROM lunchbreaks;

SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(lunch, breaks),'%H:%i:%s') as TimeDifference 
FROM lunchbreaks;
```

See the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3379f/2)

Comment: TIMEDIFF() is used for subtracting 2 columns right Sir Edper, but i need to Add the colums. Please help.

Comment: @Aljie: I made a mistake on that one. You could use `ADDTIME()` if you want to add times or `TIMEDIFF()` if you want to see the different between two times. See my update above.

Comment: Thanks sir, but how if i want to add multiple columns with same time datatypes? ADDTIME() only works for 2 columns.